# blank Json request body in wso2 esb

Tags: wso2, esb

I am getting the Blank JSON body in request. due to that ESB is given the below error.
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: No JSON payload provided.

I am using the wso2 esb 4.9.0 version. 
request is POST.
Can you please help in that .

Comment: please share your proxy config. and the request you sent.

Comment: simple post request with out body in coming to ESB proxy .. I put some log that request is not reached to that log. if you need I can share the proxy service detail

Answer (score 0):

This is a limitation of ESB, you can either send an empty json payload as {} or you can set the Content-Type as application/xml in the request.

Answer (score 0):

According to the HTTP spec "**The Content-Type entity-header field indicates the media type of the entity-body sent to the recipient or, in the case of the HEAD method, the media type that would have been sent had the request been a GET**"

[1] https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html

So if you are defining  the media type as   "application/json", then there should be a matching  entity body for POST. That is why you need to send at-least empty JSON body.  If you don't have a body then change the resource to GET rather POST.

Answer (score 0):

But the I found the issue. yes you are right but in Wso2 ESB 4.8.1 if we pass any message with without body as post then we got the error to avoid that we had created the blank payload to call that API. as soon as I removed that blank payload issue resolved. I agreed that post need that body but I had to consume the message of other system that will provide the same (Post with body).
one more thing. if any one put log as full then also you will get the same error.